# How to check if an offspring is younger than its parents?

Tags: r

I would like to check whether whether an individual is indeed younger than its parents. Every individual has an ID, year of birth, MomID and DadID. Dataset is a dataframe. Anyone have an idea?

| ID | Year | MomID | DadID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1975 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 1975 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 1976 | NA | NA |
| 4 | 1977 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1973 | 3 | 2 |

It would be nice if the results say for which individual offspring is not younger than the parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` to get corresponding `Year` of Mom and Dad and compare them with the original `Year`.

```
df <- transform(df, is_Younger_than_Parents = Year > Year[match(MomID, ID)] & 
                                              Year > Year[match(DadID, ID)])
df

#  ID Year MomID DadID is_Younger_than_Parents
#1  1 1975    NA    NA                      NA
#2  2 1975    NA    NA                      NA
#3  3 1976    NA    NA                      NA
#4  4 1977     1     2                    TRUE
#5  5 1973     3     2                   FALSE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Year = c(1975L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 
1973L), MomID = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L), DadID = c(NA, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```